# In R, is it possible to install packages onto a disk that is "not writable"?

Tags: r

I am currently on a Linux server that is not writable due to permissions issues but am able to access R. The problem is, certain packages are not installed on the server and I am unable to install it as is shown in this output:

```
> install.packages("MASS")
Installing package into '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages("MASS") :
  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Would you like to use a personal library instead?  (y/n) y
Would you like to create a personal library
~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0
to install packages into?  (y/n) y
Error in install.packages("MASS") : 
  unable to create '~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0'
In addition: Warning message:
In dir.create(userdir, recursive = TRUE) :
  cannot create dir '/home/user', reason 'Permission denied'
```

Is it possible to install packages or introduce packages in such a way that doesn't rely on touching the disk itself? Thanks!

Comment: You can run code online at http://www.r-fiddle.org.  They allow you to use packages.  I just tried MASS and it worked.

Comment: Is there no directory at all on which you have write-access? Is even `dir.exists(tempdir())` or `file.create(tempfile())` FALSE?

Comment: I ran `file.create(tempfile())` and it comes to TRUE. However, I was unable to run `dir.exists(tempdir())`, is it an R or Linux command?

Comment: dir.exists(tempdir()) is an R function that will return TRUE or  FALSE if tempdir() exists. What do you mean when you say you couldn't run it? Error message?